# Why is Exception subclass not caught by except clause?

Tags: python, inheritance

Why the except part won't work and it raises an error?

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

try:
    1/0
except MyException:
    print('something')
```

Result:

```
ZeroDivisionError Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Comment: What makes you think that's not working correctly? 1/0 throws a _sibling_ of MyException.

Comment: So, how should I use it ? @jonrsharpe

Comment: It's hard to say, because it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. If you want to catch the division by zero, catch _that_ error (or another that's actually in its hierarchy: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).

Comment: Try deriving `MyException` from `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: @martineau that still wouldn't work, because 1/0 throws the parent not the child. You'd have to somehow insert the new error _above_ the one that's being thrown.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: You're right…my suggestion wouldn't help.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want to have a custom Error class and do something with the error message.

Comment: Then read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions, but what does that have to do with dividing by zero?

Answer (score 1):

`ZeroDivisionError` is not equal to and does not inherit from `MyException`.
they both just inherit from `Exception` just like most other builtin exceptions.
for more information take a look at the python Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html